# No puedo editar un cliente

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual agrego el cliente satisfactoriamente y tambien al darle el boton editar traigo los datos de la base de datos pero al momento de querer editar modificando algun dato me dice que a sido cambiado exitosamente pero no hace absolutamente nada, espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar el error. les adjunto capturas del codigos.

De antemano Muchas gracias!

> Codigo Html editar cliente.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditarCliente" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
     <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar cliente</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarNombre" id="editarNombre" class="form-control input-lg" value="Nombre cliente" required>

            <input type="hidden" name="idCliente" id="idCliente" required>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarRut" id="editarRut" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Rut" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarDireccion" id="editarDireccion" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Direccion" required>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="email" name="editarCorreo" id="editarCorreo" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Correo" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarTelefono" id="editarTelefono" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Telefono" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <?php

    $editarCliente = new ControladorClientes();
    $editarCliente -> ctrEditarCliente();

    ?>
      </form>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

> Cliente.js

```
   $(".btnEditarCliente").click(function(){
      var idCliente = $(this).attr("idCliente");
      

      var datos = new FormData();
      datos.append("idCliente", idCliente);

      $.ajax({
          url:"ajax/clientes.ajax.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: datos,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(respuesta){
          console.log("Datos AJAX: ",respuesta);
           $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta['nombre']);
           $("#idCliente").val(respuesta['id_clientes']);
           $("#editarRut").val(respuesta['rut']);
           $("#editarDireccion").val(respuesta['direccion']);
           $("#editarCorreo").val(respuesta['correo']);
           $("#editarTelefono").val(respuesta['telefono']);
         
            },     
          error : function(respuesta) {
              console.log("Error",respuesta);
          } 
        });


      })
```

> cliente.modelo.php

```
<?php
    require_once "conexion.php";
    class ModeloClientes{

        static public function mdlEditarCliente($tabla,$datos){
            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET nombre=:nombre, rut=:rut, direccion=:direccion, correo=:correo, telefono=:telefono WHERE id_clientes=:id_clientes");
            
            $stmt -> bindParam(":nombre",$datos['nombre'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id_clientes",$datos['id_clientes'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":rut",$datos['rut'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":direccion",$datos['direccion'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":correo",$datos['correo'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":telefono",$datos['telefono'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if($stmt->execute()){

                return "ok";
                
            }else{

                return "error";
            }

            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt = null;
        }


        static public function mdlMostrarClientes($tabla,$item,$valor){

            if($item!=null){
                $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
                $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item,$valor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> execute();
                return $stmt->fetch();
            }else{
                $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
                $stmt -> execute();
                return $stmt->fetchAll();
            }
            
            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt=null;

        }

        static public function mdlIngresarCliente($tabla,$datos){

            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (nombre,rut,direccion,correo,telefono) VALUES (:nombre,:rut,:direccion,:correo,:telefono)");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":nombre",$datos['nombre'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":rut",$datos['rut'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":direccion",$datos['direccion'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":correo",$datos['correo'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":telefono",$datos['telefono'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
                return "error";
            }
            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt = null;
        }

        static public function mdlActualizarCliente($tabla,$item1,$valor1,$item2,$valor2){
            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET $item1 = :$item1 WHERE $item2 = :$item2");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item1,$valor1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item2,$valor2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
                return "error";
            }
            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt = null;

        }

        static public function mdlBorrarCliente($tabla,$datos){
            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE id_clientes = :id_clientes");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id_clientes",$datos,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
                return "error";
            }
            $stmt -> close();
            $stmt = null;

        }
    }
```

> cliente.controlador.php

```
<?php

    class ControladorClientes{

        static public function ctrEditarCliente(){

            if(isset($_POST['editarNombre'])){

                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['editarNombre']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[.\-\-a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$_POST['editarRut']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[#\.\-a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["editarDireccion"]) &&
                    preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["editarCorreo"]) && 
                    preg_match('/^[+\-\.\-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['editarTelefono'])){

                    $tabla = "clientes";

                    $datos = array( "nombre"=>$_POST['editarNombre'],
                                    "id_clientes"=>$_POST['idCliente'],
                                    "rut"=>$_POST['editarRut'],
                                    "direccion"=>$_POST['editarDireccion'],
                                    "correo"=>$_POST['editarCorreo'],
                                    "telefono"=>$_POST['editarTelefono']);

                    $respuesta  = ModeloClientes::mdlEditarCliente($tabla, $datos);

                    if($respuesta=="ok"){
                        echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Success!',
                                text: '¡El cliente ha sido actualizaddo correctamente!',
                                icon: 'success',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                }).then((result)=>{
                                    if(result.value){
                                        window.location = 'clientes';
                                    }
                                })
                        </script>";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Error!',
                                text: '¡No puedes usar caraceres especiales en el campo nombre!',
                                icon: 'error',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                })
                        </script>";
                }
                }
        }

        static public function ctrCrearCliente(){
            if(isset($_POST['nuevoNombre'])){

                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['nuevoNombre']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[.\-\-a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$_POST['nuevoRut']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[#\.\-a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoDireccion"]) &&
                    preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["nuevoCorreo"]) && 
                    preg_match('/^[+\-\.\-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['nuevoTelefono'])){

                    
                    $tabla = "clientes";
                    $datos = array("nombre"=>$_POST['nuevoNombre'],
                                    "rut"=>$_POST['nuevoRut'],
                                    "direccion"=>$_POST['nuevoDireccion'],
                                    "correo"=>$_POST['nuevoCorreo'],
                                    "telefono"=>$_POST['nuevoTelefono']);

                    $respuesta  = ModeloClientes::mdlIngresarCliente($tabla, $datos);
                    if($respuesta=="ok"){
                        echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Ingresado!',
                                text: '¡Registro Exitoso!',
                                icon: 'success',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                }).then((result)=>{
                                    if(result.value){
                                        window.location = 'clientes';
                                    }
                                });
                        </script>";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Error!',
                                text: '¡No puedes usar caraceres especiales en el campo!',
                                icon: 'error',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                });
                        </script>";
                }
            }
        }

        static public function ctrMostrarClientes($item,$valor){
            $tabla="clientes";
            $respuesta = ModeloClientes::mdlMostrarClientes($tabla,$item,$valor);
            return $respuesta;
        }


        static public function ctrBorrarCliente(){
            if(isset($_GET['idCliente'])){
                $tabla = "clientes";
                $datos = $_GET['idCliente'];
                
                    $respuesta = ModeloClientes::mdlBorrarCliente($tabla,$datos);
                    if($respuesta=="ok"){
                        echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Success!',
                                text: '¡El cliente ha sido borrado correctamente!',
                                icon: 'success',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                }).then((result)=>{
                                    if(result.value){
                                        window.location = 'clientes';
                                    }
                                })
                        </script>";
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

> cliente.ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once "../controladores/clientes.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/clientes.modelo.php";
class AjaxClientes{

    

    /*=============================================
    EDITAR CATEGORÍA
    =============================================*/ 

    public $idCliente;

    public function ajaxEditarCliente(){

        $item = "id_clientes";
        $valor = $this->idCliente;

        $respuesta = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

        echo json_encode($respuesta);

    }
}

/*=============================================
EDITAR Cliente
=============================================*/
if(isset($_POST["idCliente"])){
    $editarCliente = new AjaxClientes();
    $editarCliente -> idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $editarCliente -> ajaxEditarCliente();

}
```

> Mensaje al editar un registro
> [image: Mensaje al editar un registro]

> Dato sigue exactamente igual
> [image: Dato sigue exactamente igual]

Comment: Saludos. De momento solo se me ocurre que verifques lo que llega al PHP; en tu "Js cliente editar" hay un `$(".btnEditarCliente").click(...);` pero que no existe en el html el `btnEditarCliente`; en ese mismo, tu `$(this).attr("idCliente")` devolveria null, asi como los demás datos no los pasas; solo estas agregando `datos.append("idCliente", idCliente);` .. bueno, la sentencia devuelve OK por que no hay error en ella, que al parecer no reciba y/o no afecte datos no implica deba devolver error.

Comment: Roberto de antemano agradecer tu respuesta, tengo agregado el btneditar pero lo agrege mas arriba 

<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btnEditarCliente" idCliente="'.$value["id_clientes"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarCliente"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button> 

esa es, esta agregado, se observa en el html, lo agregare al codigo de arriba, lo otro lo que comentas sobre el @[$(".btnEditarCliente").click(...);] no entendi tu explicacion no soy muy avanzado en el tema y me cuesta entender un poco estimado.

Comment: disculpa, no se como poner el codigo como lo hiciste tu, estoy tratando de arreglarlo, saludos. @RobertoLeOr

Comment: De nuevo saludos. Con las aclaraciones e imagen que agregas, revise más a fondo tu código. Ciertamente ya no le encuentro; solo me resta sugerirte revises los datos que se reciben; en la parte del `Ajax`que corresponde a `success: function(respuesta)`habilitar el `console.log("idCliente","Respuesta");`que allí tienes pero que de la manera `console.log("Datos AJAX: ",respuesta);` principalmente para que verifiques el valor de `respuesta['id_clientes']`para comprobar es un dato no `NULL`y ademas existente en tu Base de Datos.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr    

 `Datos AJAX:  
<code>{0: "6", 1: "asdsadsadas", 2: "187776666", 3: "holaaaa", 4: "prueba@gmail.com", 5: "878788787", id_clientes: "6", nombre: "asdsadsadas", rut: "187776666", direccion: "holaaaa", correo: "prueba@gmail.com", …}`

Comment: otra parte 

` __proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()

`

Comment: ¿Cuando dices *no hace absolutamente nada* a qué te refieres? ¿Qué debe hacer y dónde debe hacerlo?

Comment: @RobertoLeOr estimado, acabo de actualizar la problemática, esta mas clara y completa, también agregado imágenes, espero pueda orientarme, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

**Primer error:** No estás agregando todos los datos a la petición AJAX:

```
$(".btnEditarCliente").click(function(){
  var idCliente = $(this).attr("idCliente");
  var datos = new FormData();

  // Solo estás enviando idCliente
  datos.append("idCliente", idCliente);

  // Te falta agregar todos los datos necesarios
  datos.append('editarNombre', $("#editarNombre").val());
  datos.append('editarRut', $("#editarRut").val());
  datos.append('editarDireccion', $("#editarDireccion").val());
  datos.append('editarCorreo', $("#editarCorreo").val());
  datos.append('editarTelefono', $("#editarTelefono").val());

  // Aquí abajo ejecutas la petición por AJAX
  // ...
});
```

**Segundo error:** Estás llamando un método para mostrar cliente, no para actualizar:

```
<?php
require_once "../controladores/clientes.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/clientes.modelo.php";
class AjaxClientes{

    
    public $idCliente;

    public function ajaxEditarCliente(){

            $item = "id_clientes";
            $valor = $this->idCliente;
            // Mostrar cliente, debería ser ctrEditarCliente()
            $respuesta = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);
            echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
}


if(isset($_POST["idCliente"])){
    $editar = new AjaxClientes();
    $editar -> idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $editar -> ajaxEditarCliente();
}
```

**Tercer error:** Los scripts de respuesta no se ejecutarán, eso debes manejarlo en `success` del AJAX:

```
                if($respuesta=="ok"){
                    echo"<script>
                        Swal.fire({ 
                            title: 'Success!',
                            text: '¡El cliente ha sido actualizaddo correctamente!',
                            icon: 'success',
                            confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                            }).then((result)=>{
                                if(result.value){
                                    window.location = 'clientes';
                                }
                            })
                    </script>";
                }
```

Tu función AJAX espera un JSON, pero estás enviando HTML. Esto te va a funcionar en una petición normal y deberías buscar la forma de identificar si se trata de una petición AJAX para saber qué información devolver.

Por ejemplo, puedes definir una constante en clientes.ajax.php `define('AJAX', 1);` y modificar el código de respuesta:

```
if($respuesta == 'ok') {
    if(defined('AJAX')) {
        // Agregar estado de respuesta
        $datos['respuesta'] = 'ok';
        // Enviar datos como JSON
        echo json_encode($datos);
        // Aquí debería terminar la ejecución del script, para evitar enviar más cosas
        exit;
    } else {
        // No es petición AJAX, aquí va la ventana de diálogo SWAL
    }
}
```

Finalmente, en AJAX analizas la respuesta:

```
  $.ajax({
      url:"ajax/clientes.ajax.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: datos,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(respuesta){
          if(respuesta.respuesta == 'ok') {
             $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta['nombre']);
             $("#idCliente").val(respuesta['id_clientes']);
             $("#editarRut").val(respuesta['rut']);
             $("#editarDireccion").val(respuesta['direccion']);
             $("#editarCorreo").val(respuesta['correo']);
             $("#editarTelefono").val(respuesta['telefono']);
         } else {
             // Hubo algún error, mostrar mensaje
         }
      }
```

Comment: Gusto saludarte amigo, gracias por responder, en la descripccion del problema, agrege codigo final de mi js en el cual esta agregado lo que comentas, comentarte tambien que tbn tengo un usuario el cual agrega, modifica, edita y elimina y lo hace perfectamente de la misma estructura que esta planteada, tbn tengo otro sis que esta de la misma forma y funciona perfecto, entonces, cual es mi error?.

de antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, revisa nuevamente

Comment: gracias por tu instruccion, comentarte que la verdad me marie un poco jejej como no soy muy entendido en el tema y me cuesta maquetar lo que me explicas, agradecerte por aquello, tratare de hacer lo que me dices, pero creo que no podre ya que no entiendo mucho.

Comment: lo otro estimado, por que el otro que esta igualmente maquetado (usuario) me funciona a la perfeccion y este no? (obviamente cmbiando los datos necesarios)

Comment: disculpa amigo, acabo de actualizar el planteamiento, estaba desorganizado, poca información, ahi esta claro, espero su ayuda, de antemano. gracias @Triby

Comment: Cuando dices que no eres _muy entendido en el tema_, ¿a qué te refieres exactamente, no sabes programar?

Comment: Solo lo básico, soy en ingeniero en informática pero nunca fue mi fuerte esto y por temas de pandemia eh tenido que realizar estos tipos de trabajos me cuesta asociar datos y entender el funcionamiento de cada función. (estructura) pero dispuesto aprender por supuesto.

Comment: no me funciono su solucion estimado, que podrá ser? @Triby