# Problemas con la edicion de un registro plantilla AdminLTE 3

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual agrego el cliente satisfactoriamente y también al darle el botón editar traigo los datos de la base de datos pero al momento de querer editar el cliente, modificando algún dato del cliente me dice que a sido cambiado exitosa mente pero no cambia ningún registro, pero dice que a sido cambiado lo cual no ocurre, espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar el error. les adjunto capturas del códigos.

PD: En el sistema también tengo agregado a registro, editar y eliminar usuario, lo cual el editar utilice su estructura y el de usuario funciona perfectamente, pero en clientes tengo el problema.

De antemano Muchas gracias!

> Codigo Html editar cliente.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditarCliente" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
     <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar cliente</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarNombre" id="editarNombre" class="form-control input-lg" value="Nombre cliente" required>

            <input type="hidden" name="idCliente" id="idCliente" required>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarRut" id="editarRut" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Rut" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarDireccion" id="editarDireccion" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Direccion" required>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="email" name="editarCorreo" id="editarCorreo" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Correo" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="editarTelefono" id="editarTelefono" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Telefono" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <?php

    $editarCliente = new ControladorClientes();
    $editarCliente -> ctrEditarCliente();

    ?>
      </form>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

> Cliente.js

```
   $(".btnEditarCliente").click(function(){
      var idCliente = $(this).attr("idCliente");
      

      var datos = new FormData();
      datos.append("idCliente", idCliente);

      $.ajax({
          url:"ajax/clientes.ajax.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: datos,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(respuesta){
          console.log("Datos AJAX: ",respuesta);
           $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta['nombre']);
           $("#idCliente").val(respuesta['id_clientes']);
           $("#editarRut").val(respuesta['rut']);
           $("#editarDireccion").val(respuesta['direccion']);
           $("#editarCorreo").val(respuesta['correo']);
           $("#editarTelefono").val(respuesta['telefono']);
         
            },     
          error : function(respuesta) {
              console.log("Error",respuesta);
          } 
        });


      })
```

> cliente.modelo.php

```
<?php
    require_once "conexion.php";
    class ModeloClientes{

        static public function mdlEditarCliente($tabla,$datos){
            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET nombre=:nombre, rut=:rut, direccion=:direccion, correo=:correo, telefono=:telefono WHERE id_clientes=:id_clientes");
            
            $stmt -> bindParam(":nombre",$datos['nombre'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id_clientes",$datos['id_clientes'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":rut",$datos['rut'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":direccion",$datos['direccion'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":correo",$datos['correo'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":telefono",$datos['telefono'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if($stmt->execute()){

                return "ok";
                
            }else{

                return "error";
            }

            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt = null;
        }


        static public function mdlMostrarClientes($tabla,$item,$valor){

            if($item!=null){
                $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
                $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item,$valor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> execute();
                return $stmt->fetch();
            }else{
                $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
                $stmt -> execute();
                return $stmt->fetchAll();
            }
            
            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt=null;

        }

        static public function mdlIngresarCliente($tabla,$datos){

            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (nombre,rut,direccion,correo,telefono) VALUES (:nombre,:rut,:direccion,:correo,:telefono)");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":nombre",$datos['nombre'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":rut",$datos['rut'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":direccion",$datos['direccion'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":correo",$datos['correo'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":telefono",$datos['telefono'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
                return "error";
            }
            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt = null;
        }

        static public function mdlActualizarCliente($tabla,$item1,$valor1,$item2,$valor2){
            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET $item1 = :$item1 WHERE $item2 = :$item2");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item1,$valor1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item2,$valor2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
                return "error";
            }
            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt = null;

        }

        static public function mdlBorrarCliente($tabla,$datos){
            $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE id_clientes = :id_clientes");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id_clientes",$datos,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return "ok";
            }else{
                return "error";
            }
            $stmt -> close();
            $stmt = null;

        }
    }
```

> cliente.controlador.php

```
<?php

    class ControladorClientes{

        static public function ctrEditarCliente(){

            if(isset($_POST['editarNombre'])){

                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['editarNombre']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[.\-\-a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$_POST['editarRut']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[#\.\-a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["editarDireccion"]) &&
                    preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["editarCorreo"]) && 
                    preg_match('/^[+\-\.\-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['editarTelefono'])){

                    $tabla = "clientes";

                    $datos = array( "nombre"=>$_POST['editarNombre'],
                                    "id_clientes"=>$_POST['idCliente'],
                                    "rut"=>$_POST['editarRut'],
                                    "direccion"=>$_POST['editarDireccion'],
                                    "correo"=>$_POST['editarCorreo'],
                                    "telefono"=>$_POST['editarTelefono']);

                    $respuesta  = ModeloClientes::mdlEditarCliente($tabla, $datos);

                    if($respuesta=="ok"){
                        echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Success!',
                                text: '¡El cliente ha sido actualizaddo correctamente!',
                                icon: 'success',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                }).then((result)=>{
                                    if(result.value){
                                        window.location = 'clientes';
                                    }
                                })
                        </script>";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Error!',
                                text: '¡No puedes usar caraceres especiales en el campo nombre!',
                                icon: 'error',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                })
                        </script>";
                }
                }
        }

        static public function ctrCrearCliente(){
            if(isset($_POST['nuevoNombre'])){

                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['nuevoNombre']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[.\-\-a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$_POST['nuevoRut']) &&
                    preg_match('/^[#\.\-a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoDireccion"]) &&
                    preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["nuevoCorreo"]) && 
                    preg_match('/^[+\-\.\-a-zA-Z0-9ñÑaáéÉíÍóÓúÚ ]+$/',$_POST['nuevoTelefono'])){

                    
                    $tabla = "clientes";
                    $datos = array("nombre"=>$_POST['nuevoNombre'],
                                    "rut"=>$_POST['nuevoRut'],
                                    "direccion"=>$_POST['nuevoDireccion'],
                                    "correo"=>$_POST['nuevoCorreo'],
                                    "telefono"=>$_POST['nuevoTelefono']);

                    $respuesta  = ModeloClientes::mdlIngresarCliente($tabla, $datos);
                    if($respuesta=="ok"){
                        echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Ingresado!',
                                text: '¡Registro Exitoso!',
                                icon: 'success',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                }).then((result)=>{
                                    if(result.value){
                                        window.location = 'clientes';
                                    }
                                });
                        </script>";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Error!',
                                text: '¡No puedes usar caraceres especiales en el campo!',
                                icon: 'error',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                });
                        </script>";
                }
            }
        }

        static public function ctrMostrarClientes($item,$valor){
            $tabla="clientes";
            $respuesta = ModeloClientes::mdlMostrarClientes($tabla,$item,$valor);
            return $respuesta;
        }


        static public function ctrBorrarCliente(){
            if(isset($_GET['idCliente'])){
                $tabla = "clientes";
                $datos = $_GET['idCliente'];
                
                    $respuesta = ModeloClientes::mdlBorrarCliente($tabla,$datos);
                    if($respuesta=="ok"){
                        echo"<script>
                            Swal.fire({ 
                                title: 'Success!',
                                text: '¡El cliente ha sido borrado correctamente!',
                                icon: 'success',
                                confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                                }).then((result)=>{
                                    if(result.value){
                                        window.location = 'clientes';
                                    }
                                })
                        </script>";
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

> cliente.ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once "../controladores/clientes.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/clientes.modelo.php";
class AjaxClientes{

    

    /*=============================================
    EDITAR CATEGORÍA
    =============================================*/ 

    public $idCliente;

    public function ajaxEditarCliente(){

        $item = "id_clientes";
        $valor = $this->idCliente;

        $respuesta = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

        echo json_encode($respuesta);

    }
}

/*=============================================
EDITAR Cliente
=============================================*/
if(isset($_POST["idCliente"])){
    $editarCliente = new AjaxClientes();
    $editarCliente -> idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $editarCliente -> ajaxEditarCliente();

}
```

> Mensaje al editar un registro
> [image: Mensaje al editar un registro]

> Dato sigue exactamente igual
> [image: Dato sigue exactamente igual]

> Pantallazo console.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Seccion Red

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar la salida en consola para ver que error te muestra?

Comment: Adjunte el pantuflazo en la publicación, puedes revisarlo.

@SaulEspinoza

Comment: Pero en esa captura no se ve la respuesta de ajax, sólo errores de la plantilla que no tienen nada que ver. Has revisado la petición y respuesta en la pestaña de red?

Comment: @JesúsFranco adjuntare pantallazo de la pestaña de red.

Comment: @JesúsFranco puedes chekear.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No puedo editar un cliente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366450/no-puedo-editar-un-cliente)

Comment: Que cosa? @Triby

Comment: Estás duplicando una pregunta y lo peor es que ni siquiera te has tomado la molestia de tratar de aplicar las sugerencias.

Comment: En la pestaña de red no se ve nada, si eso es lo que ocurre entonces ni siquiera está haciendo la petición de red, o no estás mostrando los datos que envía.

Comment: @Jesus Franco gusto saludarte, si me eh dado cuenta, al ver en la pestaña de red veo el ajax de cliente al traerme los datos y al editar no muestra nada, que podrá ser? Saludos!!